# RequireJS async loading leads to poor user experience (UX)?

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, requirejs, amd

I'm using RequireJS to help me manage complex relationships/dependencies between some of my homegrown Javascript modules. It works very well for that -- loads them in the correct order based on their dependencies.

I'm also using RequireJS to load known libraries such as jQuery and KnockoutJS.

This being said, my issue is this -- let's say I have a simple login form page. It uses jQuery to enable some interaction (example: validating input, etc.). As such, I use RequireJS to include jQuery in my page's Javascript code. But, since RequireJS require() calls are asynchronous, there's a potential 'delay' between the moment the page is shown to the user, and the moment the jQuery library is loaded and kicks in.

So here's my problem: in the hypothetical scenario where the jQuery library takes a while to load, I want to prevent the user from being able to manipulate/submit the form until jQuery has kicked in. So, at the moment, the login form is initially hidden (displays a 'Loading...' message), and at the end of my require() async callback, once jQuery is loaded and applied, I make the form visible.

I find that this leads to a somewhat poor user experience -- you load the page, it's missing stuff at first (showing 'Loading...'), and then the form appears. In most cases it loads pretty quickly, so the page looks like it 'blinks' as it goes from the 'Loading...' phase to showing the full form almost instantly.

I've been thinking of moving the big libraries (jQuery, KnockoutJS) outside of RequireJS for that reason.

Is this normal or expected? Am I approaching this wrong?

**TL;DR version: since RequireJS's require() mechanism is asynchronous... if your page needs some modules to work properly, do you hide the page's contents until the modules are loaded, and then make the page's contents visible in the end? Would this be considered poor UX?**

Answer (score 1):

Ah you probably aren't optomising your requirejs assets,

i use gruntjs to compile all my requirejs assets into one big js file,

if you leave requirejs unoptimized yes it can all be a bit slow, for dev it's great to easily have everything link dynamically, for production it's normally best to compile everything together into one big file for download speed (every file adds about 100ms and 1.3k onto your page load)

should mention for dynamic javascript perhaps created by php or something, you can ignore them from the concat process using empty:, and then add a query string which will make you able to using a .php file end ending, but your normally better writing static code which uses a dynamic json feed loaded by the static code

Some links about the requirejs optomiser, ps you can do this your self by concating all the files together in a bat/sh script yourself

http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html

you will probaly need to repeat your main.js javascript lookup rules in your grunt file, if you have any special library locations or shims in place

example grunt file i use currently

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
// Project configuration.
...
    requirejs: {
        production: {
            options: {
                // REMEMBER TO DUPLICATE CHANGES IN MAIN.JS, example dynamic javascript created by ajax, and static javascript in library folder
                paths: {
                    "moment": "../shared/js/moment/2.5.0/moment.min",
                    "dynamic.ottconfig": "empty:"
                },
                shim: {
                    "lib.filesaver": {deps: ["shim.blob"]},
                                ...
                },
                name: "main", // link to almond.js or requirejs.js
                appUrl: "./web/tmp/js",
                baseUrl: "./web/tmp/js",
                out: "web/bin/js/main.min.js",
                optimize: "uglify2",
                preserveLicenseComments: false,
                generateSourceMaps: true,
                insertRequire: [ "main" ]
            }
        }
    },
    ...);
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-requirejs');
    // Default Production Build task(s).
    grunt.registerTask('default', [
    ...
            'requirejs',
            ...
    ]);
};
```

Comment: Once the JS files are optimized/grouped together, does it mean they can then be loaded synchronously? A.K.A. using <script src="my-grouped-file.min.js" />, or is it still asynchronous but with shorter load time?

Comment: kind of both, if you just have all static files then loaded synchronously <script src="my-grouped-file.min.js" /> (i would recommend keeping the dynamic version for dev though!), but if you have some files which are truely dynamic then everything you haven't put "empty:" will be synchronously and the dynamic scripts will load asynchronous (note by synchronously i mean non-blocking synchronously, everything happens once the big files is loaded)